# SharePoint Online give administrator access to My Site of all users

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to migrate user data from a network share to the "Personal Documents" folders of the user's My Site.
Therefore I want to give an Administrator full access to the My Site of all users.

I've been able to grant an Administrator full access to a particular My Site using the SharePoint Online Administration (in the manage profiles section, https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/tenantprofileadmin/ProfMngr.aspx), and this works fine.
However, I'd like to give the permissions to all My Sites in one go. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above is for on premise installations though my understanding Is that you are using office365. To do this you click Admin in the top right of your screen and go to the sharepoint admin section and manage site collections. Find your mysite site collection and manage this and add an additional owner. This will give access to all mysites.

Tal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to add yourself to WebApplication user policy group with full control.

https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx
-> select  https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com web application -> owners -> manage administrators -> add your account to web application administrators group (2nd row)

Best regards
Andrew

Comment: One of my users has a OneNote file that I'm supposed to move to another tenant.  Using this method above I can get into their personal area, but I can't find any OneNote file, even though his OneNote says it is syncing with that personal site's address.